# Active Server Page Error with WebMatrix

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

When I execute my ASP pages I get this error in the browser:

Active Server Pages (ASP) erreur 'ASP 0131'

Parent path unauthorized /Admin/nimda_cansu.asp, ligne 1

The include file '.. / Inc / Inc.asp' can not contain '..' to indicate the parent directory.

At the fist ligne of the asp code I have this:

```
<!--#include file="../Inc/Inc.asp"-->
```

thank you for your Help!

Comment: what is the IIS version?

Comment: Im using IIS Express !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just changed the relative path `file="../Inc/Inc.asp"` to a virtual path and deleted the first two dots `virtual="/Inc/Inc.asp"` also don't forget to activate the parent path !
Now it's working for me !